# Compile MarbleWidget with VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, c++11

I'm trying to follow [this](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Marble/MarbleCPlusPlus) tutorial on MS VisualStudio2010 Professional. I'm pretty new to developping under Windows and have some difficulties with "translating" the build command.
I included the Qt-Path and the QtLibrarys via the Projectsettings, but I have some problems by adding the "marblewidget" library.
As I found out, it is not possible to mix different compilers, so I checked out the marble-widget from git and compiled it according to [this](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Marble/WindowsCompiling#Compiling_Marble_using_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B) Tutorial. That worked fine so far and gave me a working Marble.exe with a 9.8MB sized DLL (marblewidgetd.dll).
I included all the marble-header files to VS and copied the DLL into the workspace.

But when I try to compile the "HelloMarble"-Project I get this Error:

```
my_marble.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void__thiscall Marble::MarbleWidget::setMapThemeId(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setMapThemeId@MarbleWidget@Marble@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z)" referenced in function "_main"
```

And some other LNK2001 errors.

When I try to add the DLL to the linker, I get this Errormessage:

```
<path>\marblewidgetd.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E0
```

Any ideas how I could get this example running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't link against *.dll files at compile time, you link against *.lib files

Comment: yeah I speculated that to, but compiling my marblewidget-project as described hasn't produced some *.lib file, only the dll file ... what have i done wrong?